# How to get address of a slice?

Tags: rust

How to convert slice to either `*const ()` or `usize`?

```rust
&[ T ] -> *const ()
```

Of course, I understand it will downgrade fat pointer to slim one dropping length.
My use case is comparing addresses of two slices.

Comment: there is talk about usize being what it should always be, a size, specially a usize just can't represent a pointer, cause a pointer is a pointer https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95228

Comment: @Stargateur While that is true, getting the address out of a pointer is very unlikely to stop working, even with simple casting. The discussion is about the opposite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is calling [`<[T]>::as_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr) or [`<[T]>::as_mut_ptr()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_mut_ptr).

You can also do that the way those functions implement it, by first casting the slice into a pointer to slice and then casting the resulting pointer into a thin pointer to the element type:

```rust
let slice: &[T];
slice as *const [T] as *const T;
```

However, those functions are provided in std exactly for you to don't do that.

If all you want is to compare addresses, you can call [`std::ptr::eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/fn.eq.html) directly with the slices.

Comment: Note: `something as *const _ as *const ()` works even if something is not a slice.

Comment: @Kos Not a slice but?

Comment: It works even if T is ordinary slim reference. In case of `T::as_ptr()` something has to be slice.

Comment: @Kos [It doesn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=874b8cffc3ad160ba9d81c7570d50e69).

Comment: But I agree you should not use it, like I said: "However, those functions are provided in std exactly for you to don't do that." Mistyping is part of the problem.

Comment: `std::ptr::eq()` is good thing, but it does not allow comparing addresses of references on different types

Comment: @Kos If you want that (and it's not clear to me why), then indeed you have to cast the pointer somewhere, either by `as` or better, by [`cast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.cast).

Comment: Chayim, Thanks for the elaborated answer :)